# .bbl clears itself after compiling

Tags: bibliographies, miktex

I am using `MiKTeX 2.9` with pdfLaTeX, MakeIndex and BibTeX and I'm trying to create a bibliography at the end.
Here is my problem:

- I put the sources into my bibliography (it is in a separate `.bbl`-file), for example like this (note: after compiling everything will be shown in my bibliography):

  `\begin{thebibliography}{}
  \bibitem{IL}"'Inquiry Learning"', Dr. Hasan Caliskan, 2012
  \end{thebibliography}`
- In the document I'm using I refer to the document for example like this (note after compiling some times the bibliography is empty again?!?!):

  `Trying to build an example. Refer to:\cite{IM}`

It's really annoying to rebuild the bibliography again and again. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: The `.bbl` file is meant to be built by a program such as `bibtex` or `biber`.  Running one of these programs will overwrite the file.  However running just `pdflatex` will not.  Writing a `bbl` yourself, is not how to use `bibtex`.  You should put the data in a `.bib` file in the syntax `bibtex` expcets, see the useful [Tame the Beast document](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tamethebeast)

Comment: @Andrew Swann: Thank you, that was the solution! Would you mind to post this as a real answer? Didn't know this before. I thought it was a issue due to the use with MiKTeX.

Comment: As far as I know, MiKTeX accepts any extension for BibTeX files. The problem wouldn't show with other TeX distributions, because they would look for `file.bbl.bib`. In any case, always use `\bibliography{file}` without specifying the extension (and name the bibliography file with the extension `.bib`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.bbl` file is meant to be built by a program such as `bibtex` or `biber`. Running one of these programs will overwrite the file.  However running just `pdflatex` will not.

Writing a `.bbl` yourself, is not how to use `bibtex`. You should put the data in a `.bib` file in the syntax `bibtex` expcets, see the useful [Tame the Beast document](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tamethebeast).  For example, your entry above may be written as

```
  @Book{IL,
    title = {Inquiry Learning}, 
    author = {Caliskan, Hasan}, 
    year = {2012}
  }
```

but should probably include further information such as the publisher etc.